# addNew() in joomla 3

Tags: toolbar, joomla3.0

Kindly help me how to call the function addnew() in joomla 3.0

protected function addToolbar()  {
        $canDo  = ComboscategoriesHelpersLendr::getActions();

```
    // Get the toolbar object instance
    $bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');

    JToolbarHelper::title(JText::_('Combos Category'));

   if ($canDo->get('core.admin'))
    {
        JToolBarHelper::addNew();
       /* JToolbarHelper::preferences('com_comboscategories');*/
        JToolBarHelper::save();
        JToolBarHelper::cancel();
        JToolBarHelper::deleteList();
        JToolBarHelper::publishList();
        JToolBarHelper::unpublishList();
    }
}
```

I add this function in html.php file. Where this function has to be called.